# How can I display only joined groups where I am a member (php)?

Tags: mysql

**TABLES**

users:

[image]

group:

[image]

example:

```
| groupID | name    | createdBy | description | groupIdentity |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    | test    | user2     | etst        | 4455          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    | another | user2     | etst        | 4220          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    3    | new     | user1     | test        | 4221          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

group_members:

[image]

example:

```
| groupID | memberID | userStatus | groupIdentity |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1       | user1    |   1        | 4455          |
---------------------------------------------------
| 2       | user1    |   0        | 4220          |
---------------------------------------------------
| 3       | user2    |   1        | 4221          |
---------------------------------------------------
```

`userStatus` values:

- 0 = the request is pending to the group
- 1 = the user is a member in
  the group
- 2 = the user is a moderator in the group
- 3 = the creator of
  the group

---

I would like to display all joined without my own groups that I have created  groups for a particular user even if the `userStatus` is equal to 1 or 2 but not 0 and 3.

I could make that work to do not display own created group.

**My current query:**

```
$currentUser = $_SESSION['name'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM group_members INNER JOIN `group` ON group.groupID = group_members.groupID 
        WHERE createdBy <> '$currentUser'";
```

Also tried with

```
$currentUser = $_SESSION['name'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM group_members INNER JOIN `group` ON group.groupID = group_members.groupID 
        WHERE createdBy <> '$currentUser' AND userStatus <> '0'";
```

but it still shows that group as well where I  sent a request to join in.

Also tried with `if` statement:

```
if ($row['userStatus'] >= '1') {
  $groupID = $row['groupIdentity'];
  $groupTitles = $row['name'];
  echo "
   <a href='?key=$groupID'>
        <div class='mini-card my-cards'>
          <span class='groupBtnsWrapper'>
            $notifications
          </span>
          <div class='div2'>
            $groupTitles
          </div>
        </div>
        </a>
      ";
   }
```

The wrong output because I have sent a request to the "another" group

[image: The Wrong output]

Correct output would be:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to remove PHP from the equation because what you need is a mysql query. Once have it, you may start with PHP code, but remember you must use prepared statements for your queries

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh okay :)

Comment: Note that DISTINCT * is an oxymoron. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Okay. I tried without it as well but still displaying that group as well where I am applying for.

Comment: So now you know what to do

Comment: @Strawberry Not really. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you want? perhaps a sample output would be great.

Comment: table schema and sample data would be a  help  perhaps?!

Comment: Please provide few rows of sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Why not try without `DISTINCT` and instead of `userStatus <> '0'`, try with `AND userStatus NOT IN ('0','3')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Let me know if it works. I've used table name `grp` instead of `group` as it is a reserved keyword and should be avoided.

Assuming that you want the group names where user has joined and the status is either 1 or 2.

```
select A.name from grp A, group_members B 
where A.groupIdentity  = B.groupIdentity 
AND B.groupIdentity IN ( 
    select groupIdentity from grp_mem 
    where userStatus IN (1, 2) 
    and memberID == "user1" 
)
```

php code:

```
    $currentUser = $_SESSION['name'];
    $sql =     "select A.name from grp A, group_members B 
        where A.groupIdentity  = B.groupIdentity 
        AND B.groupIdentity IN ( 
            select groupIdentity from grp_mem 
            where userStatus IN (1, 2) 
            and memberID == '$currentUser'  
        )";
```

Comment: I need the query for PHP

Comment: Can't you build that? First try this SQL query on your SQL console and check if this is what you want.

Comment: @Chris_00 I've added the PHP statement.

Comment: Thanks I did it differently, but I didn't the you can combine multiple expectations like: ` userStatus IN (1, 2)` . That was helpful tho. So just +1

Comment: It has some syntax error in the PHP query and this is not the one that I was looking for.

Comment: Well, the question was about mysql query which works. And what else were you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM group_members INNER JOIN `group` ON group.groupID = group_members.groupID 
    WHERE createdBy <> '$currentUser' AND userStatus <> '0' GROUP BY group.groupID
```

Note change the table name group to some else, it is a reserved keyword in mysql

[see mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: ok could you post the image of the database column with some data to understand more.

Comment: No, i want the sample row data. And change the join types, may be helps

Comment: Sorry, but explain the question again

Comment: There is no problem in SQL for which the above might be a reasonable solution :-( See the mysql doc